# php Open tga and save tga

Tags: php, imagick, tga

I am trying to edit a TGA (32 bit). The goal is that I open the file, add some text and save it again as TGA (32 bit).

I managed to open a TGA file using some scripts, but it seems that I need imagick to save it also as a TGA. (but with imagick i can't open a TGA).

Does someone has an example of saving a tga file 32 bit? For opening I could also work from a .jpg file

Thanks

Wouter

Comment: I doubt you will find an example in php. TGA was never accepted against file formats like tiff and the like and is more or less dead these days.

Comment: There is indeed no much information about this topic. Problem is that I would have a background-generator for a game. And the files are tga.

In fact a jpg to tga conversion could do the trick too.. But the 32 bit seems to be a 'problem'